# How to add different css classes for every template in joomla

Tags: css, class, templates, joomla

I have site [www.kadamjay.kg](http://www.kadamjay.kg). I am using RT template and every language has deifferent templates.Therefore 
when I am adding some to particular class it changes on only one template. Also there is no extra template in path. I have tried to give class to every page. But it's a lot of pages therefore it's not a variant.

Answer (score 2):

I found solution.We can add class suffix for every module and every page therefore it takes little bit time but it's very comfortable in usage.